# How to list all parameters in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql, variables, parameters, psql

I was wondering if there's a parameter for the currently authenticated `psql` user?

But then I wonder a more broader question - how can I just see what all the paremeters are?
I might discover some interesting parameters if I could see a whole list of them?

I'm only seeing online how to get the value of one parameter. Not a list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not have such a thing as server-side session variables, so it's not clear what you are asking about.

Some PLs (such as PL/Python, PL/Perl) have session variables (`%_SHARED` in PL/Perl, `GD` and `SD` in PL/Python for example), but they are internal to the PL, not part of the server proper.

`psql` also has variables, which you can set with `\set`, and you can get a list with the same command.  I suppose that's not what you want though.

Maybe you refer to so-called custom `GUC` configuration parameters, which are sometimes abused as session variables. You can get a list of those using `SHOW ALL` or `SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_settings`.

Answer (score 2):

Alvaro has answered the question how to list your current parameter values.

To get the authenticated user, you can call the SQL function `session_user`:

```
SELECT session_user;
```

The currently effective user can be seen with

```
SELECT current_user;
```

In `psql`, you can see details about your current database session with

```
\conninfo
```

Answer (score 1):

Nonsense. Try these two SQL statements:

```
set foo.bar =42;
```

and then:

```
select current_setting('foo.bar');
```

You’ve just set, and read an entity that the PostgreSQL doc doesn’t seem to name. You might call `x.y` a “user-defined session parameter”. Where is its value held? Server-side, of course.

I too would like to know how to list the names of all currently defined such entities—system-defined, like TimeZone, and user-defined.

— bryn@yugabyte.com

Comment: NOTE: the sql statement `show all` sounds promising. But it lists only all the system-defined  parameters. The doc describes it thus: “SHOW — show the value of a run-time parameter”.

This gets the value of `foo.bar`:

```
show foo.bar;
```

But `show all` doesn’t include `foo.bar`.

I called this a “session parameter” just to echo the wording of the title of this thread.

— bryn@yugabyte.com

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW ALL` below can show all parameters according to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-show.html):

```
SHOW ALL;
```

This is how `SHOW ALL` works below:

```
postgres=# SHOW ALL;
            name            |   setting   |                                     description

----------------------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 allow_in_place_tablespaces | off         | Allows tablespaces directly inside pg_tblspc, for testing.
 allow_system_table_mods    | off         | Allows modifications of the structure of system tables.
 application_name           | psql        | Sets the application name to be reported in statistics and logs.
 archive_cleanup_command    |             | Sets the shell command that will be executed at every restart point.
 archive_command            | (disabled)  | Sets the shell command that will be called to archive a WAL file.
 archive_mode               | off         | Allows archiving of WAL files using archive_command.
 archive_timeout            | 0           | Forces a switch to the next WAL file if a new file has not been started within N seconds.
 array_nulls                | on          | Enable input of NULL elements in arrays.
 authentication_timeout     | 1min        | Sets the maximum allowed time to complete client authentication.
 autovacuum                 | on          | Starts the autovacuum subprocess.
...
```

And, you can show one specific parameter with `SHOW` as shown below:

```
postgres=# SHOW allow_in_place_tablespaces;
 allow_in_place_tablespaces
----------------------------
 off
(1 row)
```

But, you cannot show more than one parameters with `SHOW` as shown below:

```
postgres=# SHOW allow_in_place_tablespaces, allow_system_table_mods;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: show allow_in_place_tablespaces, allow_system_table_mods;
```

So to show more than one parameters, use `SELECT FROM pg_settings` below:

```
postgres=# SELECT name, setting, short_desc FROM pg_settings WHERE name IN ('allow_in_place_tablespaces', 'allow_system_table_mods');
            name            | setting |                         short_desc
----------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------------------
 allow_in_place_tablespaces | off     | Allows tablespaces directly inside pg_tblspc, for testing.
 allow_system_table_mods    | off     | Allows modifications of the structure of system tables.
(2 rows)
```

In addition, [current_setting()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE) can show one specific parameter as shown below:

```
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('allow_in_place_tablespaces');
 current_setting
-----------------
 off
(1 row)
```

But, you cannot show more than one parameters with `current_setting()` as shown below:

```
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('allow_in_place_tablespaces', 'allow_system_table_mods');
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type boolean: "allow_system_table_mods"
LINE 1: ...ECT current_setting('allow_in_place_tablespaces', 'allow_sys...
```